# How to specify the length of an edge in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

In a directed graph, if there is a cycle, the graphviz makes that edge really short.

Is there a parameter that would let me change the length of the cyclic edge, so that 
the graph looks a bit uniform.

```
digraph ER {
  rankdir="LR";
  //orientation=landscape;
    node [shape=ellipse, fontsize=30];
  {node [label="Original"] old;}
  {node [label="Final"] new;}
  {node [label="Intermediate"] ir;}

old -> ir [label="suggest", fontsize=30];
ir -> ir [label="validate", fontsize=30, len=f];
ir -> new [label = "finalize", fontsize=30];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that the following attribute `nodesep` worked to solve this problem with sfdp.

From [*nodesep | Graphviz*](https://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/nodesep/):

For layouts other than `dot`

> nodesep affects the spacing between loops on a single node, or multiedges between a pair of nodes.

Note that this is a graph attribute, so the value is the same for all edges in the graph.

Answer (score 20):

Edit: Sorry, my answer will make edges longer, but not the self referencing edges you need.

*len* doesn't work in dot, but *minlen* does.

https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:minlen

```
x->y
[minlen=5]
```

Answer (score 9):

`len` doesn't works in dot, but you can try this trick:

```
digraph G {
rankdir=LR
a->b[dir=both]
b->c[dir=both,label="        "]// Just use the space to increase the edge length
}
```

If `rankdir=TB`, use `label="\n"` (repeat the `\n` as necessary) to increase the length.

[image]

Comment: what if I want the edge to be very short? Like `label="   "`?

Answer (score 4):

You can make the cyclic edge longer by adding a bunch of invisible cyclic edges before your visible one, like this:

```
digraph ER {
  rankdir="LR";
  //orientation=landscape;
    node [shape=ellipse, fontsize=30];
  {node [label="Original"] old;}
  {node [label="Final"] new;}
  {node [label="Intermediate"] ir;}

old -> ir [label="suggest", fontsize=30];
ir -> ir [style="invis"]
ir -> ir [style="invis"]
ir -> ir [style="invis"]
ir -> ir [style="invis"]
ir -> ir [label="validate", fontsize=30, len=f];
ir -> new [label = "finalize", fontsize=30];
}
```

[image: OP's corrected graph]

Answer (score 3):

From dot(1):

```
len=f sets the optimal length of an edge.  The default is 1.0.
```

Comment: for `dot` must work `minlen`, but in this case it does not work anyway :(

Comment: From the very same manpage, the line above it reads: *(neato and fdp-specific attributes)*. Since `fdp` and `neato` are specifically meant for *undirected* graphs rather than directed graphs, `len` doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 3):

There's another approach that I now use for this:

I use graphviz to output the file in dot format

```
dot -T dot -Kneato -o ./positioned.dot ./input.dot
```

This file will contain the Bezier curve definitions for every edge.
I manually change the points to curve the way I want it to draw.

This may look a little daunting at first but once you figure out, how they work this isn't hard, I'm inching towards a script that will do this for me automatically

then re-run dot with your edited positioned file as the input

```
dot -T png -Kneato -O ./positioned.dot
```

With this approach I've pretty much turned dot into my text based visio replacement

Answer (score 2):

In .dot language, the edge connects two notes with different ranks.
The length of edge is equal to (difference in ranks)*ranksep

default ranksep (in graph attribute) is 0.75 inch, so edge of adjacent nodes will be 0.75 inch.

To reduce the edge length, you set ranksep into a smaller value in graph atrribute