# Edges inside records in graphviz/dot

Tags: record, graphviz, dot

I want to highlight a relationship inside a record in graphviz (v 2.38.0) by running a straight edge between two of the elements in that record. However, dot does everything it can to run the edge outside the record node.

The following example shows my problem.

```
digraph {
  rankdir = LR;
  splines = line;

  i1; i2; i3;
  mux [shape=record,label="{  {<i1>i1|<i2>i2|<i3>i3} | MUX | <o1>o1}"];
  o;

  i1 -> mux:i1;
  i2 -> mux:i2;
  i3 -> mux:i3;
  mux:o1 -> o;

  mux:i1:e -> mux:o1:w [color=red];

}
```

[image]

I want the red edge to be a straight line between the ports, inside the record. I don't care if the edge overlays the record label.

Is there a way to force an edge to be a straight line ignoring obstacles, or otherwise instruct dot that an object should ignore if it's overlaying nodes/labels?

This issue is similar to [Graphviz edges between ports belonging to the same record node look bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079921/graphviz-edges-between-ports-belonging-to-the-same-record-node-look-bad), which doesn't have an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `splines = curved;`

```
digraph {
  rankdir = LR;
  splines = curved;

  i1; i2; i3;
  mux [shape=record,label="{  {<i1>i1|<i2>i2|<i3>i3} | MUX | <o1>o1}"];
  o;

  i1 -> mux:i1;
  i2 -> mux:i2;
  i3 -> mux:i3;
  mux:o1 -> o;

  mux:i1:e -> mux:o1:w [color=red];


}
```

[image: png]

Comment: Thanks.This solves the immediate problem of routing edges inside records. Unfortunately, the rest of my diagram requires straight edges in order to render well.